# lib64 on Android?

Tags: android

What is lib64/ld-linux-x86-64? is it part of android's AOSP files I downloaded or something that I need to install separately?

from my laptop: I do have installed the lib64 but I suppose I need ld-linux-x86-64.so?

```
laptop:/usr/lib64$ ls
libfakeroot
```

However this is below is the warning I get when I try to compile the AOSP.

```
laptop:/media/HDD3_AOSP/AOSP_ANDROID$  source build/envsetup.sh
including device/asus/grouper/vendorsetup.sh
including device/asus/tilapia/vendorsetup.sh
including device/generic/armv7-a-neon/vendorsetup.sh
including device/generic/armv7-a/vendorsetup.sh
including device/generic/mips/vendorsetup.sh
including device/generic/x86/vendorsetup.sh
including device/google/phantasm/vendorsetup.sh
including device/lge/mako/vendorsetup.sh
including device/samsung/maguro/vendorsetup.sh
including device/samsung/manta/vendorsetup.sh
including device/samsung_slsi/arndale/vendorsetup.sh
including device/samsung/toroplus/vendorsetup.sh
including device/samsung/toro/vendorsetup.sh
including device/ti/panda/vendorsetup.sh
including sdk/bash_completion/adb.bash
laptop:/media/HDD3_AOSP/AOSP_ANDROID$  lunch full-eng
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2: No such file or directory
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2: No such file or directory
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2: No such file or directory
============================================
PLATFORM_VERSION_CODENAME=AOSP
PLATFORM_VERSION=4.2.1.2.4.8.16.32.64
TARGET_PRODUCT=full
TARGET_BUILD_VARIANT=eng
TARGET_BUILD_TYPE=release
TARGET_BUILD_APPS=
TARGET_ARCH=arm
TARGET_ARCH_VARIANT=armv7-a
HOST_ARCH=x86
HOST_OS=linux
HOST_OS_EXTRA=Linux-2.6.32-41-generic-i686-with-Ubuntu-10.04-lucid
HOST_BUILD_TYPE=release
BUILD_ID=OPENMASTER
OUT_DIR=out
============================================
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ld is the linker-  it links to gether object files into an executable.  If it isn't part of the downloaded build, you'll need to grab a copy of it.  My guess is the gnu version would be good enough, but I can't swear to that.